# Multiple simuntaneous changesets with Git

Tags: git, version-control

My company is evaluating moving to a new SCM system, and git is one of the final contenders being considered.  Before we began, we came up with a list of use-cases that needed to be supported.

One use-case for which I don't have a solid answer with git is simultaneously working on multiple "changesets" in a single "project".

In our current SCM, you associate a file with a "task" when you "check it out".  As long as your changes are in different files, you can have as many "tasks" active as you want.

In my experience with git, you don't associate changes into a "changeset" (commit) until you stage them for commit.  However, there is only one staging area, so you can only do this for one "changeset" at a time (and can't associate a summary/description yet).

There is also "stash", but the typical use of this would be to incorporate multiple logical changes into one build to run tests against, so they need to be simultaneously "active".

As I write this post, a possible workflow comes to mind: make one commit per "changeset" as you start it, and commit + 'rebase -i'/squash it into the appropriate commit as you make further changes.  However, that seems overly complex and likely would not be well-received.

Is there a better way?  Or a compelling justification for why we should stop using this workflow (would need to be very compelling)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you're talking here about "tasks" sounds like branches in Git. Please note that you have no need to push any branch you create in your local repository to your central "reference" repository (seems like enterprises can't live without one anyway). So why not just have a branch for each "task" you want to do and then merge them into an integration branch as they're completed?

Comment: @kostix Thanks for your input.  Indeed, I agree branches may a good fit (see my response to one of the answers below).
The biggest issue is that while you have one branch ("task") active in your workspace, the others will not be.  So, creating a build that includes all of the "tasks" while you're still working on them would involve a lot of tedious, repetitive merging to yet another branch local branch.

Answer (score 0):

We switched to git over a year ago as a large development group and it has served us very well.

You're right, that when using git you only have a single work space available at a time.

git doesn't really track an individual file, like other SCMs. Even when you do a rename, it is really stored as a delete and add under the new name. So your workflow of adding a file with a task would need to be altered.

Instead you'd add your task as a branch.  Branches in git are extremely lightweight and work very well.  An example workflow would be that you have your release code in the master branch (trunk), and as new tasks come up, you'd make a branch of master, make your changes there, validate, test, approve and merge into master.  You can either keep the branch as a reference or clean it up.

Where you may have multiple versions of a product to support and patch, adopting a release branch system may work better for you. master is reserved for your next release, and as versions are shipped, create a release/<version> branch.  That allows you to go back later and hotfix a version and re-build confident that you're using the same code base you shipped.  Also provides a good place to do metrics on work done between releases.

Stash, is really used to temporarily preserve changes as you switch between branches. For example, if you started work on a task and realize after several edits that you're in the wrong branch. Stash will move those changes into a holding space, allowing you to checkout the correct branch and pop your changes back to your workspace.

If you have multiple developers working at the same time, you probably want to steer clear of a rebase method and use a merge methodology.  Because the git repository is a chain of commits that include the parent commit's hash, rebasing causes commits to be re-written and as a result, requires developers to re-clone from the server hosting your repository. The merge method simply requires you to merge other's changes that were pushed to the server before pushing your changes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
To clarify a bit, I'm not looking for multiple workspaces.  Rather, a way to allow a developer to multi-task on multiple changesets is desired.  Further, being able to create a build during development including all of these changes at once is ideal.
I think we have a good story already for the overall branch/merge strategy, this question is specific to the developers local repository before pushing anything out to be adopted by any public branch.

Comment: (continued)
Is what you're suggesting to have one branch per changeset, requiring switching between branches to make associated changes and merging them into a single branch to make a build?
When I mentioned rebasing, I was meaning just to do the following:
1. Commit "Task #1"
2. Commit "Task #2"
3. Commit "Task #3"
4. Commit change meant as part of "Task #2"
5. rebase -i "Task #1", just using it to squash that last commit into "Task #2", not actually changing the base of the code thread.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a UI-level feature, rather than something which needs to be core to the SCM.  I know that (for example) Eclipse layers functionality like this on top of any SCM you care to use.

The difficulty with not having it in the SCM itself is remembering which files go with which change.  I'd agree with JasonM that the correct thing to do here is to use branches locally rather than mixing changes in with each other -- consider why you're mixing up changes, and what you do when two changes you're working on need to touch the same file.  Various places I've worked have had similar workflows to that which you describe, mostly so that people aren't tied to one thing at once and mostly by remembering which files were supposed to go where (rather than using tooling).  All of them would have benefited from being able to use multiple local branches instead of mixing changes together, although I'm sure not everyone would have seen it that way, especially at the start.

Comment: Thank you.  That's interesting.  I had not considered labeling changesets at a layer above the SCM during the period before they are committed (did I understand you correctly?).
This requirement is likely to have come from momentum with workflows that follow from our current SCM.  The limitation with not being able to have the multiple "tasks" modify the same file if you want to have them currently active in the same project is just known and accepted.

Comment: (continued)
I am of the mind that we just need to have a reasonable way that this _can_ be accomplished, for people who will continue with their old workflows (even when better options are presented, there will always be those that resist changing).  However, it doesn't need to be as easy or smooth to do as more common workflows or more git-appropriate workflows.